# Mule Flow setup, Payload, Java component

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio

Mule : Could you please help following query : In Anypoint Mule IDE,             How to  assign values to a Payload like this "Value1|Value2|Value3|Value4|.." ? and then assign the payload to Java component in Mule?

I tried following approach:
(1) define Java component and return String object as output (by implementing callable method as below):

public class InputToJavaComponent implements Callable {

```
@Override
public Object onCall(MuleEventContext eventContext) throws Exception {

    return "Value1|Value2|Value3";
}
```

I was checking if is there any other simple way to achieve same thing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both approaches as follow works fine:
(1)

```
@Override
public Object onCall(MuleEventContext eventContext) throws Exception {
    return "Value1|Value2|Value3";
}
```

(2)

```
[flowVars.Value1+'|']#[flowVars.Value2+'|']#[flowVars.Value3+'|']#[flowVars.Value4]
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try like this in set payload and let us know whether it work or not

## [flowVars.Value1+'|']#[flowVars.Value2+'|']#[flowVars.Value3+'|']#[flowVars.Value4]

Comment: Thank you Koteswarrao,  I will try and update you accordingly, the callable implementation technique works as well, I was planning to try some other technique.

Answer (score 0):

hi i tried as the below way and it was working fine for me, try in this way

## [sessionVars.Value1+'|']#[sessionVars.Value2+'|']#[sessionVars.Value3+'|']#[sessionVars.Value4]